# Modification of Beamer theme

Tags: beamer, themes

I would like to modify this theme.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black} \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

\mode <all>

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Task}
Task.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I would be glad to get different footer in this way. I would like to have exactly the same one as it is used in Torine style (downloaded from http://blog.barisione.org/2007-09/torino-a-pretty-theme-for-latex-beamer/) with the only little change, where the three stripes would start on the left and go to the right (the number page is then also on the left). Does anyone know how to modify this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply copy the definition of the `footline` template and introduce the desired modifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\DeclareOptionBeamer{compress}{\beamer@compresstrue}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer

\mode<presentation>

\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usecolortheme{orchid}

% Colors.
\definecolor{beamer@blendedblue}{rgb}{0.137,0.466,0.741}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=beamer@blendedblue}
\setbeamercolor{titlelike}{parent=structure}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black} \setbeamercolor{item}{fg=black}

% The footline template is a modification of the one used in the
% Torino theme, Copyright 2007 by Marco Barisione
\setbeamercolor*{lineup}{parent=palette primary}
\setbeamercolor*{linemid}{parent=palette secondary}
\setbeamercolor*{linebottom}{parent=palette tertiary}
\setbeamercolor*{page header}{parent=titlelike}
\mode <all>

% some lengths (the height of the lines)
\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linemid}{.015\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@lineup}{.025\paperheight}

\newlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}
\setlength{\beamer@decolines@linebottom}{.01\paperheight}


% String used between the current page and the total page count.
\def\beamer@decolines@pageofpages{/}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{decolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  % First line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt,right]{}%
    \hbox{\usebeamerfont{palette primary}\footnotesize\insertframenumber{} \beamer@decolines@pageofpages{} \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Second line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Third line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Task}
Task.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thanks lot. This is better, however still not exactly what I wanted. The theme Torine looks nice for me with the different length of the three lines that is lost in your modification.

Comment: @Laura you said  "the three stripes would start on the left and go to the right" so I acted accordingly thinking that you wanted full width lines. Give me some minutes to add the easy modifications.

Comment: @Laura: I've updated my answer with the changes. I hope this is what you want :-)

Comment: Thanks. It's almost what I wanted :-). Would it be possible to move the page numbering to the right side and put it on the second line?

Comment: @Laura sure! I updated my answer; hope everything is OK now, but if not, let me know ;-)

Comment: @Laura I updated my answer with a new atttempt :-). Something like that?

Comment: @Laura perhaps you missed my last comment... I updated my answer. Is something like this what you want?

Comment: @Gonzola It is ok now. I would maybe make the numbering of the pages a little big bigger (the same height as the height of the first line) and also put it more to the right side almost at the end of the right side, but never mind. It is only detail. It's fine like this as well.

Comment: @Laura I've updated my answer.